# unable to parse specific value from a particular column of a csv file

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I am making a predictive model to predict revenue and trying to parse this *'cast'* value from the data frame as it is not a *list* or a *dict*

```
x['cast']
```

And the output is

```
0    [{'cast_id': 4, 'character': 'Lou', 'credit_id...
1    [{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Mia Thermopolis'...
2    [{'cast_id': 5, 'character': 'Andrew Neimann',...
3    [{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Vidya Bagchi', '...
4    [{'cast_id': 3, 'character': 'Chun-soo', 'cred...
5    [{'cast_id': 6, 'character': 'Pinocchio (voice...
6    [{'cast_id': 23, 'character': 'Clyde', 'credit...
7    [{'cast_id': 2, 'character': 'Himself', 'credi...
8    [{'cast_id': 1, 'character': 'Long John Silver...
9    [{'cast_id': 24, 'character': 'Jonathan Steinb...
Name: cast, dtype: object
```

I need all the *'character'* values in a list.
but when I try

```
x['cast'][0]['character']
```

It throws this error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Help me out with this please.

Comment: I just searched , it is a json file, but I am still not able to load it as ' json.load(x['cast']) '

Comment: What does `type(x.at[0, 'cast'])` show? Long story short: is it a string or a list?

Comment: @SergeBallesta - Check first sentence - `I am making a predictive model to predict revenue and trying to parse this 'cast' value from the data frame as it is not a list or a dict `

Comment: @jezrael: You are probably right, but in that case, my opinion is that it should be fixed *before* feeding the dataframe.

Comment: IMHO, you should wonder where this column values come from, and how it is possible to avoid the problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta @jezrael -- it is a series of strings                                                                     `type(x['cast'])                gives               pandas.core.series.Series`                                             while                                                                                                                                        `type(x['cast'][0])             gives               str`

Comment: So the true question is where that piece of *censored* comes from, and can you possibly fix it before loading that in your dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

First convert json to list of dictionaries and then get values from first list by key of dict:

```
import ast

mask = x['cast'].notna()

x.loc[mask, 'cast'] = x.loc[mask, 'cast'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
#alternative
#x.loc[mask, 'cast'] = x.loc[mask, 'cast'].apply(pd.io.json.loads)
x.loc[mask, 'cast'] = x.loc[mask, 'cast'].apply(lambda x: x[0].get('character', 'not match data'))
```

EDIT:

If still problem use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'cast':[[{'cast_id': 4, 'character': 'Lou'}], np.nan]})

x['cat'] = x['cast'].astype(str).str.extract("'character': '([^'']+)'")
print (x)
                                   cast  cat
0  [{'cast_id': 4, 'character': 'Lou'}]  Lou
1                                   NaN  NaN
```

Comment: @AAKARSHYADAV - Can you test now?

Comment: @AAKARSHYADAV - can you check now?